# Is there a minimal, pre-built solution for hosting a large collection of files?

Tags: apache, server, looking-for-a-script, linux

My Google-fu has failed me on this one. Every time I search for something like this all I get is a bunch of vulnerability reports. I feel like this should be pretty straightforward, but I'm not having any luck.

I have an internal web/fileserver whose functionality I'd like to integrate. Currently, there is a large data partition with a bunch of files (git repo) only accessible via SSH, and a separate web server (Apache2 on Debian). <s>Note that the majority of files have whitespace in their path.</s> (Bulk-renamed this away.)

Is there a minimal (no database or frills) CGI script or something that will dynamically load a directory listing and make links to the files, and maybe some basic search, too? A tie-in to find/locate via bash would be about the right amount of functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use Apache's [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_autoindex.html)? It does just what you describe (minus the search) by exposing files in directories. Or are you looking for something more than basic directory listing?

Comment: For one, I didn't know about it. For two, I am looking for a bit more functionality, or at least the possibility of adding it myself.

Comment: Does it have to be a CGI script, or are you open to others (e.g. PHP/Python etc.)?

Comment: I'm open to pretty much anything. Doesn't have to be CGI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Filenice](http://filenice.com/) is a PHP directory browser with search functionality.

Comment: Very nice. Looks like exactly what I'm looking for. I'll give this a try.

Comment: This has a few caveats: doesn't handle whitespace or "&" in the path, only does substring search. Otherwise, this looks pretty cool.